# Add value and text to Label - VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to put a variable and some text (in this case "%") to label in VBA. Below code does not work:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim CurrentValue As String
    CurrentValue = DLookup("AvgOfutil_MPS", "AverageDescending", "[dates]")
    Me.Label34.Caption = Round(CDbl(CurrentValue), 2) + "%" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work in what way?  What is the value of `CurrentValue`? (Always use `&` not `+` for string concatenation)

Comment: (Always use & not + for string concatenation) - Worked perfectly, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim CurrentValue As String
    CurrentValue = DLookup("AvgOfutil_MPS", "AverageDescending", "[dates]")
    Me.Label34.Caption = Cstr(Round(CDbl(CurrentValue), 2)) & "%" 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering that you define a String and then calculate a Double based on that String. Why do you not use Double right away?

To your questions, as Alex K. mentioned: try "&" to concatenate.

Comment: I thought that DLookup returns String value, so i could then convert it to number. In my case CurrentValue is something like this 21.2354325. I will try use double right away. BTW "&" helped :)